# How is my String Index Out of Bounds?

Tags: java, string, io, java.util.scanner

GOAL: To ask user for # of points. Then user will input `"1 4"`, where 1 is the `x` and 4 is the `y`. I will take the sub-string to get 1 and 4 separately then make them an `int` so I can make them a `Point`.

I keep getting "`java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1`"
**this is taking place on line 25, but not 24**. When I use 3 instead of the length it also gives me this error.

This is a fragment of code:

```
public String run() { 
    String line = ""; 
    String first = ""; 
    String second = ""; 
    int j = 0; int n = 0;
    System.out.println("How many inputs do you want to enter?");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(j == 0){

      if(sc.hasNextInt()){
        n = sc.nextInt();
        Point[] points = new Point[n];
        sc.close();
        j++;
      } 

      else {
        System.out.println("invalid input");
      }
    }

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++){
      System.out.println("Enter x and y:");
      line = scan.next();
      first = line.substring(0,1);
      second = line.substring(2,line.length());      

    }

    scan.close();
    origin(points);

    return ""; 
}
```

Comment: You don't need to declare more than one Scanner

Comment: Don't `close` the `Scanner` on `System.in`, **that** *also* closes `System.in`

Comment: Also your `for loop` condition might be an issue as well. Shouldn't it be `for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)` ??

Comment: Running this code, I get `NoSuchElementException` on the scanner... probably because System.in was closed

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you. I'm not sure what your `j` variable was doing, your for-loop for the points was going out of bounds on the array, you are closing `System.in` between two separate `Scanner`s, and obviously something wrong is happening with your `substring` logic.

This code fixes all those problems and runs great for me.

```
public String run() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int n = numberPrompt("How many inputs do you want to enter?\n", "Invalid input");
    Point[] points = new Point[n];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        System.out.println("Enter x and y:");
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        String[] data = line.split("\\s+");
        if (data.length >= 2)
        {
            int x = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
            int y = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);
            points[i] = new Point(x, y);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(points));

    origin(points);

    return "";
}

private int numberPrompt(String prompt, String error) {

    Integer number = null;
    boolean isValid;
    String input;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
        isValid = true; // reset the validity
        System.out.print(prompt);
        input = sc.nextLine();

        try {
            number = Integer.parseInt(input);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            isValid = false;
            if (!(error == null || error.isEmpty())) {
                System.out.println(error);
            }
        }
    } while (!isValid);

    return number;
}
```